# Unable to pod install with multiple Library

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, alamofire

I am trying to add multiple library using pod setup, but unfortunate not success.

**My Pod Setup**

```
platform :ios, "8.0"

use_frameworks!

target 'Demo Cluster' do

  pod 'GoogleMaps'

pod 'GooglePlaces'

pod 'Google-Maps-iOS-Utils'



 pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.4'

end
```

**I get This Error**

[image: error]

Comment: Write use_frameworks! in new line

Comment: sorry ? can you explain more

Answer (score 1):

Until GoogleMaps is released as a dynamic framework, you can only support it as a transitive dependency as a library. However, as you are using a swift framework - you can't support that either. Your best option is to request Google release their libraries as a dynamic framework.

You can try to download them manually and insert them but I think it will not work neither.

I suggest you to read [this](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/2926) discussion.

Answer (score 0):

From this [dicussion](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/5624):

> Until GoogleMaps is released as a dynamic framework, you can only
>   support it as a transitive dependency as a library. However, as you
>   are using a swift framework - you can't support that either. Your best
>   option is to request Google release their libraries as a dynamic
>   framework I'm afraid.